# How do I change the field of view in the Crysis 2 Demo?

Tags: crysis-2

I want to change Field of view in Crysis 2 demo to make it wider. Is there a console like in Counter-Strike where I can type a command, or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut for Crysis2Demo.exe; in its properties write your commands:

```
E:\Games\Crysis2Demo\bin32\Crysis2Demo.exe +cl_fov=85+r_DrawNearFoV=85 +pl_movement.power_sprint_targetFov=85 +g_skipIntro=1 +r_Glow=0
```

Answer (score 4):

You sure can!  Heres how:

```
Open : //// C:Program Files/Electronic Arts/Crytek/Crysis 2/Demobin32/Crysis2Launcher.ini

Add the two lines :

Code:
con_restricted = 0
cl_fov = 80  (where this is your field of view setting)
```

[another link](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1775803)

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to mess around with the nitty-gritty file details, there is a GUI-based launcher for Windows: http://www.incrysis.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=33008.

It works for regular *Crysis 2*, at least.